# Lambda Calculus functions that are fixed-points of themselves

Tags: lambda-calculus, fixed-points

In general, a fixed-point of a function, $f$, is a point $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = x$.

In lambda calculus, a function can take a function, including itself, as input, so we can even ask: “is there a function that is its own fixed-point? That is, is there a function $f$ such that $f(f) = f$?”

So far we have found three sets/classes of functions that meet this criteria:

1. $S_I = \{I\}$ where $I$ is the identity function, $(\lambda x.x)$
2. $S_p = \{Pp\ |\ P \text{ is a fixed-point combinator and }$

   - $p = T = \lambda ab.a\}$
   - $p = T’ = \lambda ab.b\}$ (contributed by @mohottnad)

Since $Y$ (the $Y$-combinator) and $\Omega$ (Turing’s combinator) are each a fixed-point combinator, then $(YT) \in S_2$ and $(\Omega T) \in S_2$, meaning that $(YT)$ is its own fixed-point and $(\Omega T)$ is its own fixed-point.

Are there other classes of functions that are fixed-points of themselves?

---

#### Proof: $I$ is a fixed-point of itself

$$I(I) = I$$

#### Proof: $(PT)$ is a fixed-point of itself where $P$ is a fixed-point combinator and $p = T = (\lambda ab.a)$

\begin{align}
(PT)(PT) &= (T(PT))(PT) \\
&= ((\lambda ab.a)(PT))(PT) \\
&= (\lambda b.PT)(PT) \\
&= (PT)
\end{align}

#### Proof: $(PT’)$ is a fixed-point of itself where $P$ is a fixed-point combinator and $p = T’ = (\lambda ab.b)$

(contributed by @mohottnad)

\begin{align}
(PT')(PT') &= (T'(PT'))(PT') \\
&= ((\lambda ab.b)(PT'))(PT') \\
&= (\lambda b.b)(PT') \\
&= (PT')
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least I can think of another class following your line of reasoning where $T' = \lambda ab.b$, then we have:
\begin{align}
(PT')(PT') &= (T'(PT'))(PT') \\
&= ((\lambda ab.b)(PT'))(PT') \\
&= (\lambda b.b)(PT')   \\
&= (PT')
\end{align}

Please note besides Y-combinator and Turing combinator, we also have many other combinators as referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Other_fixed-point_combinators). Finally your requirement of fixed-point function $f$ here has the *idempotent* property, which can be intuitively the *identity* function $I$ and *projection* functions like the examples $T$ and $T'$ above...

Comment: Can you confirm the following definition of idempotency? A function $f$ is idempotent iff for all functions $g$ and integers $n \geq 1$, we have $f^{\circ n}g = fg$ where $f^{\circ n}$ is the $n$-fold composition of $f$.

Comment: Yes, almost except g is not a function, should be any variable in the domain of f. See wikipedea [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Idempotent_functions): *idempotent elements are the functions f: E → E such that f ∘ f = f, that is such that ∀x, f(f(x)) = f(x) (the image of each element in E is a fixed point of f)...*

Comment: Thanks. I see how $I$ is idempotent. Are you saying that $T$ and $T'$ are each also idempotent or that $PT$ and $PT'$ are each idempotent? Because $Ta = \lambda b.a$ whilst $T(Ta) = \lambda bb.a = \lambda bc.a$?

Comment: Exactly. T and T' are like projections (functions with 2 variables) to the 1st, 2nd variable. Your T is K combinator which is a projection, my T' is SK which is the other projection function...